# Explore the normal convergence and the uniform convergence of the series $ f_n(x)=\frac{x}{(1+n^2x^2)\ln x},n\geq 2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Explore the normal convergence and the uniform convergence of the series $\sum_{n}f_n$ with $f_n:\mathbb{R}_+\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f_n(x)=\frac{x}{(1+n^2x^2)\ln x},n\geq 2$.

Could you give me some hints? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{(1+n^2x^2)\log x} = \frac{x}{\log x}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+n^2x^2} \le \frac{x}{\log x}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2x^2} = \frac{1}{x\log x}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2},
$$
which is finite. Therefore we get convergence for all positive $x\neq 1$. 
We won't get uniform convergence though, since
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\left|\frac{x}{\log x}\right| = \infty.
$$